# Is it possible to send mail without SMTP settings?

Tags: php, email

Without SMTP settings like Host, Username and Password I have to send mail. Is it possible in PHP or any some other languages??

Comment: No. SMTP settings is knowing where your post office or mailbox is. Who do you give you mail to? Throw it into the air and hope the recipient catches it?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use the mail() function, it's not requiring smtp auth.

Comment: Thanks Zeflex. But I used mail function like below.
<?php
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', "Hello");
?>

But it's throwing me the error. 
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\mail_without_smtp.php on line 9

Comment: @zeflex: If the SMTP server is not requiring auth, you do not need username and password. If it does, then you do. Host is *always* necessary, directly or indirectly (on a Linux, it hands off to the mail delivery service, which should have SMTP server configured; on Windows, you generally don't have a mail delivery service, so PHP contacts SMTP server directly).

Comment: @Amadan yes I am agree for that, but usually with the mail function you know you don't need to provide the smtp auth.

Comment: @sreekanth kuriyala >> It's because you use the mail function on windows and it couldn't work if you don't provide smtp parameters. Take a look on phpmailer to be able to set the smtp params.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do that using [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. However consider then following limitations:

> **Note:** The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from
>   the Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for
>   composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a
>   MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the
>   localhost or a remote machine). Second, the custom headers like From:,
>   Cc:, Bcc: and Date: are not interpreted by the MTA in the first place,
>   but are parsed by PHP. As such, the to parameter should not be an
>   address in the form of "Something ". The mail
>   command may not parse this properly while talking with the MTA.

> **Note:** It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for
>   larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an
>   SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.